# PHP Multipart uploading

Tags: php, file-upload

Hi I'm trying to upload a PDF file into a server using multi part but it gives me error. what I have done is created a upload page,that the user uploads the PDF file and I session that target file and sent it to the codes below to sent it over to the server am I doing anything wrong below any help would be appreciated. This is the index page.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select file to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit">
</form>
```

This is the code that I send the target file to.

```
<?php
session_start();
$file = $_SESSION ["data"];
?>


<?php

define('MULTIPART_BOUNDARY', '--------------------------'.microtime(true));
$header = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.MULTIPART_BOUNDARY;
define('file', 'fileToUpload'); 

$filename = $file; 

$content =  "--".MULTIPART_BOUNDARY."\r\n".
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"".file."\"; 
filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"\r\n";

// add some POST fields to the request too: $_POST['foo'] = 'bar'
$content .= "--".MULTIPART_BOUNDARY."\r\n".
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"foo\"\r\n\r\n".
        "bar\r\n";

// signal end of request (note the trailing "--")
$content .= "--".MULTIPART_BOUNDARY."--\r\n";

$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header' => $header,
      'content' => $content,
)
));

$result = file_get_contents('//link', false, 
$context);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Why you don't use `$_FILES` superglobal variable?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov — The PHP is **sending** an HTTP request.

Comment: This looks like a very long-winded approach to the problem. I'd strongly recommend using the cURL API which has support for generating multipart requests built in.

Comment: @Quentin is there any example online on how to do it that way?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=PHP+curl+multipart